# Downgrading the model in activiti explorer

Tags: activiti

I have created a model in activiti modeler and deployed it.As there are some changes,i have edited the model and redeployed it.Each time it has created the different process definition id.so far, i have the list of process definition id's to the same model as bellow:

(testprocess:1:657516,testprocess:2:657520,testprocess:3:657524,testprocess:4:657528)

Now,for some reasons I wish to downgrade to version 3 i.e., process which is having definition id as 'testprocess:3:657524'.I have the custom Api to delete the latest deployed process and is executing successfully.In activiti explorer,under the 'Deployed Process definitions' tab I'm able to see the downgraded deployed process(i.e., process which have process definition id[PDI] as testprocess:3:657524).
[image: downgraded deployed process which is haveing the PDI as testprocess:3:657524]

I'm using Repository Service to delete the deployment.

```
 var processEngine: ProcessEngine = ProcessEngineConfiguration.createStandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration.buildProcessEngine()
  val repositoryService: RepositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService
 repositoryService.deleteDeployment("307501", true)
```

Now the deployment is deleted successfully but the model with respect to this deployment remains same as below image
As the modeler Id is same for all the process definitions,under 'Model workspace' tab it is still showing the deleted process definition model.

[image: Model workspace look]

How can i get the model with respect to process definition(PDI) as testprocess:3:657524 in 'Model workspace' tab of activiti explorer?

Comment: Can you add the custonm code you have to downgrade the deployment? As far as I can see, a model will get null when a deployment is deleted. So you will need to change the deploymentId too of the particular model when you downgrade.

Comment: Please check the code once in question.

Comment: Looking through the code, it sets model.setDeploymentId(null) (see https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/blob/master/modules/activiti-engine/src/main/java/org/activiti/engine/impl/persistence/entity/DeploymentEntityManager.java#L67). Hence, in your custom code you must get that model and change the deploymentId too I believe. I'm still not sure how it's actually still linking to your old one though ...